# Creating a report in Delphi 10.4 Community Edition

Tags: html, database, delphi, report, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm learning programming and creating an app to save all orders and offers that was given to customers. App is pretty simple, but i want to have a feature, that will print a report with data from several tables in database (like customer's personal data, my company data, items that was ordered etc). Unfortunately, I can't find any free module for that purpose - got only PrintDAT, but as far as I know, there is no option to mix data from several tables. Is there any free module, that would work with in this situation? Eventually, I was thinking about creating an HTML document with all the data, but I don't know if there is an easy way to create PDF document from HTML created in Delphi (if this is even possible)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries or other off-site resources are off-topic. Also, a simple search for *Delphi reporting* in your favorite search engine could help you. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting, as was suggested when you created your account.

Answer (score 1):

embarcadero community edition should come  with Fast Report VCL and FMX ,
*.pdf reports are possible

more information is here  : https://www.fast-report.com/en/news/show/vcl-fmx-community-edition/

Comment: I don't see any component avalaible in my IDE for Fast Report, I have found information, that it was free with version 10.3 only (source: https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/6253-how-can-i-use-fastreport-in-delphi-community-edition/), but version 10.4 doesn't have it anymore :( Is there any option or i just have to make it by HTML/PDF?

Comment: In the IDE main menu select _Tools - GetIt Package Manager_ and then search for _Fast Report_

Comment: I have 10.4 Community Edition, and I can't see Fast Report in Getit.

Comment: I don't know if it helps with HTML at all, and I've not yet tried using it for .pdf, but Skia4Delphi (available in Getit) says that it can do .pdf output.

Comment: @UweRaabe I don't see fast report in my GetIt :(

Comment: @PhilipJ.Rayment I will try that, but it's package for graphical edits? Will it be possible to access data from database?

Comment: @Morfeo  Yes, it's primarily for graphical controls, but also has a versatile text control.  I don't use databases, but you should be able to use other controls to retrieve the data and the Skia4Delphi controls for the report output.  It may not be the most efficient way to do things, but it is a free way.

Comment: @PhilipJ.Rayment, Fastreport is not in the CE getit. you can download the free version from [here](https://www.fast-report.com/en/fastreport-embarcadero-edition/)